# Rails: What is the use of web servers (Apache / nginx / passenger)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I've been learning rails for the past half year and have a few apps up on Heroku. So for me I thought deploying apps onto the world wide web was just as simple as `heroku push`. However, I just got my first internship doing Rails and one of my seniors is talking about Apache and Nginx and I'm not sure how they fit in the picture, since I thought apps consisted of only Rails + cloud app platform. I have looked it up but I still don't get how and where it affects my app life cycle. Can someone explain what/where/when of using web servers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So you've got your Rails app, and as you know you've got controllers and actions and view and what not.

When a user in their browser goes to your app on Heroku, they type in the URL which points to the Heroku servers.

The Heroku servers are web servers that listen to your users that type in the URL and connect them to your Rails application.  The rails application does its thing (gets a list of blog posts or whatever) and the server sends this information back to your user's browser.

You've been using a web server the whole time, just it was abstracted away from you and made super simple thanks to Heroku.

So the life cycle is somewhat like this:

Whilst you've been building your applications on your development machine you've probably come across the command `rails server`. This starts a program called WEBrick which is a web server, and listens on port 3000.  You go to your app via `http://localhost:3000`.

WEBrick listens on port 3000 and responds to requests from users, such as the "hey give me a list of posts" command.

When you push your code into production (in your experience via `heroku push`) you're sending your code a provider who takes care of the production equivalent of `rails server` for you.

A production setup (which your senior developers are talking about) is a bit more complex than your local `rails server` setup on your development machine.

In production you have your Rails server (often things like Unicorn, Passenger) which takes the place of WEBrick.

In a lot of production setups, another server, such as Apache or nginx is also used, and is the server that the user connects to when they go to your application.

This server exists often as a bit of a router to work out how different types of requests should be handled. For instance, requests to static files (css, images, javascript etc) that are storted on the server might just be processed directly by Apache or nginx, since it does a fantastic (and fast) job of sending static assets back to the client.

Other requests, such as "get me a list of all blog posts" get passed onto the Rails server (Unicorn, Passenger etc) who in turn do the required work and send the response to Apache/nginx, who send it back to the client.

Heroku does all this for you in a nice easy to use package, but it sounds like the place your working at manages this themselves, rather than using Heroku.  They've setup their own bunch of web servers, and will have their own way doing an equivalent of `heroku push` which will send the code to the servers, and make sure they're up and running ready to respond to user requests.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. First time I have read about Passenger/Unicorn doing the 'rails side of the server work' and Nginx/Apache doing the sending of the files. Until now I was confused about whether Nginx was the same as Passenger etc and why you needed two different server components in Production.

Answer (score 5):

Web Pages need a Web Server to make them available on the Internet.

So a site that is all static content (all just .html pages) just needs a web server and that's where Apace, nginx, etc come in.  They are web servers.

When you use frameworks like rails, an additional component is added, an application server.  This pre-processes the pages using the rails framework and then (still) uses the above mentioned web server to make the final pages (which are .html of course) available to the end users through their browser.

Passenger Phusion is an application server that, with rails will help manage and automate the deployment of code.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is a cloud service, meaning they take care of hardware and software allowing you to seamlessly publish you application without worrying about what is going on behind the scene. So the only thing you have to do is push your code to their Git and voila.

On the other hand, Rails can also be deployed on a system built by you completely from scratch, and you will be the responsible not only for the app development but also for the server maintenance and choice of the hardware and/or software. You could then choose between several application servers capable of running rails such as ngix.

Hope that helps.